# MYSQL Searching Speed In Heavy DB

Tags: php, mysql, search, logging, innodb

I want to build a very large LOG server for my application , that over than 100 user put their log data at there automatically every one hour.
I decide to use MYSQL and Innodb for this . but I have a question:

after 5 year with 100 active user that in each request put 100 byte data into DB at every hour of a day , I'll have a table with 5 x 365 x 24 x 100 = 4380000 row !!! 
and it's size will be 5 x 365 x 24 x 100 x 100 = 417MB !!!

what about Searching Speed? I think it'll be going too low!
can Mysql Handel this ?
how much take time if i want to find data of one users?

Is there is a faster way?

Comment: MySQL expects you to index your tables properly

Comment: Please Describe perfect way....can I make separate table for every user? it'll make it better?

Comment: 417 MByte is not very large for a database.  That easily fits into memory, even on my iPhone.  If you do have performance issues, then partitioning the tables and indexes should be quite sufficient for addressing them.

Comment: how much take time if I want to find an indexed data between 5 million row?

Comment: No, don't make separate tables for each user; have an indexed user_id column in your table

Comment: Some perspective:  15% of tables are bigger than 417MB or 4.38M rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests on a quite large Innodb table (10Go, 25 columns, 12 indexes, 8 foreign keys) that I have on my system. Counting the whole table is quite slow, but returning an indexed value is cost free.
Anyway if you don't need to have foreign keys checks, MyISAM would be faster than Innodb

```
MariaDB [db]> select count(1) from {table};

+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 18865472 |
+----------+
1 row in set (29.80 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from {table} where {indexed_field} = 108304177;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Answering to your comments.
Assuming your logs table look like that.

```
create table if not exists logs (
    id int(10), 
    creation_date timestamp(), 
    value int(3)
);
```

You could scheduled the creation of an aggregate table, that would be way faster to request for graph purpose

```
create table if not exists logs_aggregated (
    creation_date timestamp(), 
    nb_logs int(3), 
    value_average int(3)
);

insert into logs_aggregated values
select
    left(creation_date, 10) as creation_date, 
    count(1) as nb_logs, 
    avg(value) as value_average
from logs
group by left(creation_date, 10);
```

Comment: for example I have logs from a temperature sensor since one year ago. now I want to check them by date and extract some of them for drawing a graph.....It's not acceptable that user wait about 30 sec for each graph! what can  I do?

Comment: In that case, best way would probably to pre-aggregate, by date, data for your graph in another table.

Comment: please describe in detail

Comment: Here's a discussion of Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables